# 'System.SystemException' while webview.InvokeSript in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using following code where i get this exception

String title = (string)webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('hdnTransactionId').value;");

I use a WebBrowser control in a WP7 app and have set IsScriptEnabled to true. Then when trying to invoke a script via InvokeScript of the WebBrowser i get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a proper plug-in to invoke the script in your application. Silverlight environment allows you to call `Notify` on the `Window.external`. Here is a complete MSDN guide to invoke the script in your application.

- [MSDN Reference Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Hybrid - Applications for Mobile](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Hybrid_-_Applications_for_Mobile)

Here is diagram to understand how a plug-in works.

[image]

Hope it helps